# Grub rescue mode after deleting Ubuntu partition

Tags: partitioning, grubrescue

A year ago I installed Ubuntu accidentally and now I've deleted the partition, and after that when I restarted my computer this showed up:

```
Error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I have tried to enter the BIOS and change the boot settings so that it won't boot into grub but it didn't help.

- Intel core I5-4440
- Boot options:
- HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH24NSBO
- HARD Disk: ST500DM002-1BD142

And then UEFI and USB...

I have Windows 10 installed.

Answer (score 0):

You had grub installed in your MBR (Master Boot Record) which overwrites your windows bootloader. When you removed your Ubuntu installation , the bootloader was probably removed as well. So what you need to do is recover MBR.

To do so first get a windows live cd (8 or 10). Then boot into that cd.

When the installer starts choose your language and click next. Now in the new window that opens you can see **Repair my device** option at the bottom. Select that.

Now go to Advanced Options and launch the Command .

After command opens type ;

<kbd>bootrec /fixmbr</kbd>

This command isn't necessary but I recommend it;

<kbd>bootrec /fixboot</kbd>

Now type <kbd>exit</kbd> and reboot. Everything should work fine now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I get a windows live cd? And i installed it accidentally when i tried to just install a linux firmware

Comment: You can buy it or download windows from Microsoft and then make a USB bootable using bootable media creation tool.

Comment: Why the downvote

Comment: Don't be rude in your answers, please.  I've removed the offensive part of your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked and I managed to boot back to windows 10. :)

Comment: Good that it worked. Don't repeat that mistake again.